# Matlab parallel computing running slower than expected

Tags: performance, matlab, parallel-processing

I am trying to use Matlab parallel computing toolbox. My PC has 6 'workers' or cores. Thus, I would expect my code to run roughly 6x as fast (ie ~600% increase in speed). However, when I actually time the opertations, I find I am only getting roughly a 40% increase in speed.

Is this normal, or am I doing something wrong?

Here is my code:

```
N=5000;

%%Parrelel
pp=parpool(6)
ts=tic;
parfor i=1:12
    q=eye(N); q^-1;
end
disp(['Time for Parrelel Computation: ' num2str(toc(ts),3) 's']);
delete(pp);

%Serial
ts=tic;
for i=1:12
    q=eye(N); q^-1;
end
disp(['Time for Serial Computation: ' num2str(toc(ts),3) 's']);
```

The readout is:

> Time for Parrelel Computation: 24.6s
>
> Time for Serial Computation: 35.9s

I wouldve expected the parrelel computation to be roughly 35/6~=6s, not 24s

Any advice?

Thanks
Roman

Comment: This is perfecly normal. You never increase by 100% per worker, far from that.

Comment: Firstly, you can almost never expect a `6x` boost by using 6 workers. That can happen in theory, unlikely in practice (unless you have an extremely embarrassingly parallel task). Further, the test you are making is kind of inconclusive. You are creating and inverting an identity matrix, with such an easy task (MATLAB figures out its easy almost immediately), the bottleneck is the construction of the matrices.

Comment: You are running matrix operations, for most operations the standard implementation already uses multiple cores.

Comment: I am not sure if this is important, but you use the same q for all iterations. There could be problems writing the results into q variable. But @Daniel already told the most important thing

Comment: @Daniel, can you suggest a more fair way of testing the gains of parallel computing? 
,

Comment: @Nitish, it takes matlab just as long to invert a random matrix as it does the identity matrix (strange, I know...)

Comment: To follow up on the comment made by @Daniel, if you really want a fair comparison, you should set "maxNuMCompThreads('1')", before you run your code, so that the intrinsic multithreading in the linear algebra functions can be disabled. Also, note that PCT in MATLAB operates on multiple processes. The IPC uses the network stack, even on a single machine. This is going to incur significant overhead compare to a single session of MATLAB.

Comment: @DankMasterDan: Get the accumulated cpu load (1 core busy, 1 idle is 0.5) running it without parallel computing. Let's assume this is 0.40. Now you take the execution time and you multiply it, its `35.9*.40=14.36` in this example. This is (roughly estimated) your theoretical maximum which you could reach using 100% of the cpu without adding any IPC-communication overhead.